# Qual a diferença entre "luta" e "batalha"?

Tags: gramática, palavra-para-ideia, classificação-de-palavras

Assim como em Português temos várias palavras-curinga, o Inglês também recicla muitas palavras e duas delas me causam uma certa insegurança ao traduzir: **match** e **battle**

Num contexto esportivo, digamos... um torneio de karatê, *match* pode significar cada uma das lutas entre dois competidores mas, num cenário mais amplo, pode também representar um conjunto de lutas que cada competidor, individualmente, deve vencer a título de eliminação, antes do evento principal.

Mas **battle** (batalha) também! Pois cada luta em si é de fato uma batalha, travada entre dois competidores, mas as eliminatórias também são, só que maiores, com mais envolvidos.

Em Português, existe diferença entre ambos os termos? Caso sim, qual palavra representa cada cenário, para que eu possa manter a consistência.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Luta" soa mais como uma disputa corpo-a-corpo entre duas pessoas, em competição esportiva ou durante uma briga.  Já "batalhas" são travadas mais frequentemente durante guerras. É claro que ambos os substantivos são usados também em sentido figurado, como em "minha luta contra o câncer", "conseguimos chegar inteiros, mas foi uma batalha". O Priberam dá as seguintes definições para as duas palavras:

> lu·ta - substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Combate corpo a corpo.
> 2. Briga, disputa entre pessoas ou grupos.
> 3. Duelo, combate.
> 4. Conflito armado. = BATALHA, CONFRONTO, GUERRA
> 5. Disputa, controvérsia.
> 6. Esforço ou trabalho para atingir algo.

---

> ba·ta·lha - substantivo feminino
>
> 1. .Ação geral de guerra, entre dois exércitos ou duas esquadras.
> 2. [Figurado]  Luta.
> 3. Discussão acalorada.

Comment: Então, em Português, podem sim ser sinônimos, mas com variação de contexto. Acho que o menos errado seria, então, considerar **luta** (match) como sendo o individual e **batalha** (battle) como o todo, de escopo maior.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto  Isso, "luta" seria entre duas pessoas, e batalhas ocorrem em guerras.  Mas temos também o sentido figurado, e também aqueles casos em que o uso é idiomático.  "---- contra o câncer",  pede mais a palavra "luta" do que "batalha", "------naval" é "batalha naval" e não "luta naval", "--------livre"  é "luta livre".  etc.

Comment: Batalha remete em minha mente imediatamente a algo estratégico, grande, complexo e longo (demorado), não simplemente um combate, embora possa também ser.

Answer (score 2):

Em termos esportivos, acredito ser mais importante manter a consistência entre os esportes do que buscar o significado literal da tradução, porque a familiaridade dos interlocutores com o formato (a fim de gerar a compreensão) parece-me mais importante do que o rigor técnico.

Eu não entendo de caratê, mas, no judô, cada disputa entre dois atletas é chamada de `luta`, e o conjunto das lutas entre estes dois atletas é chamado de `série`.

No tênis, os portugueses chamam cada disputa individual de `ponto`, e o conjunto de pontos de `jogo`. Em esportes coletivos (basquetebol ou voleibol), os termos mais comuns são `partida`ou `jogo` para as individuais, e `série` e `mata-mata` para o conjunto.

Em esportes eletrônicos, cada disputa individual é uma `partida` ou um `jogo`, e o conjunto das disputas é chamado de `série`.

Procura o que proporcionar maior familiaridade para o público-alvo que você deseja atingir.

Comment: Os **portugueses** chamam *ponto* a cada disputa individual no ténis. Eu não sigo ténis, e aprendi hoje uma coisa nova! E então os brasileiros chamam-lhe o quê?

Comment: @Jacinto Também chamamos de _ponto_, mas chamamos o conjunto de pontos de _game_. E os pontos decisivos são mantidos em inglês: _game point_, _set point_, _match point_.

Answer (score 0):

Traduzo "match" como "confronto", ou "confrontar". Veja que encaixa bem nos dois tipos de uso em inglês :

When we match these two equations, we can realize that ...
Quando confrontamos (comparamos) essas duas equações, podemos perceber que ...

The match between Brazil and Germany ended 7x1.
O confronto entre as seleções Brasil e Alemanha terminou 7x1.

"Luta" me parece que se enquadra melhor com "fight".